# Condition for equality in the triangle inequality for matrix norms

Tags: matrices, inequality, linear-matrix-inequality

Say I have two matrices $A$ and $B$, which necessarily satisfy the triangle inequality for matrix norms
\begin{equation}
||A+B||\leq||A||+||B||\;.
\end{equation}
For a general matrix norm is it possible to give the conditions $A$ and $B$ must satisfy so there is equality in the above equation? If this is not possible for any matrix norm, can anyone provide me the conditions for equality when the norm in question is the nuclear norm?

I don't wish to assume anything about $A$ and $B$. They need not be positive or Hermitian.

Comment: This is not a general answer, but a sufficient condition for the nuclear norm and for the operator norm is that $A$ and $B$ share the same singular vectors, so that you can write $A+B = U( \Sigma_A + \Sigma_B) V^T$, where $\Sigma_X$ is the matrix containing the singular values of $X$ on the diagonal.
For the nuclear norm this means that the sum of the singular values of A+B is equal to the sum of the singular values of A plus the sum of singular values of B.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other conditions, but a somewhat trivial case is when $A=cB$ with $c\geq0.$